# Solving an equation for positive integral values of variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, diophantine-equations, integers, natural-numbers

Question

> Solve
>   $$y^3+3y^2+3y=x^3+5x^2-19x+20$$
>   for positive integers $x$ and $y$.

My approach:

> I factorised the equation as
>   $(y-x)(x^2+y^2+3x+3y+3)=2[(x-1)(x-10)]$
>   and got two ordered pairs of $(x,y)$ i.e. $(1,1);(10,10)$

I can't go further.

Thanks for your help.

PS: Please consider this question without my approach also, because it may mislead you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$(y+1)^3= y^3+3y^2+3y+1=x^3+5x^2-19x+21$$ 
now, since a discriminant of $5x^2-19x+21$ is $19^2-20\cdot 21<0$ we have

$$x^3<x^3+5x^2-19x+21$$

Also
$$x^3+5x^2-19x+21<x^3+6x^3+12x+8 =(x+2)^3$$

since $x^2+31x-13>0$ for positive $x$. So $$x^3<(y+1)^3<(x+2)^3$$
which is only possible iff $y+1=x+1$ so $x=y$...

Comment: Great solution. I didn't see that discriminant part, maybe that was missing in the above approach too(I think).

Comment: I don't think so. Right side is almost always positive which give us only $y\geq x$ but not $y=x$.

Comment: $y>x$ gives no solution

Comment: Ok thanks. Can't take my vote, it has been 7 minutes

Comment: @ChristianF nice